# I'm getting an error saying "raw_input() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 4 were given". I cannot figure out what went wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make codes for a simple game. The design of the game is fine. But I'm having difficulty with including a variable along with the text in the raw input function. Any help would be appreciated.

This is the code

```
while True:
    n=int(input("How many marbles to start with? ")) #Exercise 2.4
    if (n>=1) and ((n%1)==0):
        break
    else:
        print("enter a positive integer")
while n>0:
    p2=int(input("Player #1, there are",n, "marbles left. How many marbles will you take? "))
    if (p2 not in (1,2,3)) or (p2>n):
        print("not a proper input")
    else:
        n=n-p2
        if n==0:
            print("Player #1, you took the last marble and have won! ")   
        else:
            while True:
                p1=int(input("Player #2, there are",n, "marbles left. How many marbles will you take? "))
                if (p1 not in (1,2,3)) or (p1>n):
                    print("not a proper input")
                else:
                    n=n-p1
                    if n==0:
                        print("Player #2, you took the last marble and have won! ")
                    break
```

This is the error message I'm getting

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-d507a539ca61> in <module>
      6         print("enter a positive integer")
      7 while n>0:
----> 8     p2=int(input("Player #1, there are",(n), "marbles left. How many marbles will you take? "))
      9     if (p2 not in (1,2,3)) or (p2>n):
     10         print("not a proper input")

TypeError: raw_input() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concatenate the strings you are passing to [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) into a single string, rather than passing them as separate args as you are now. Replace:

```
input("Player #1, there are",(n), "marbles left. How many marbles will you take? ")
```

With

```
input("Player #1, there are " + str(n) + " marbles left. How many marbles will you take?")
```